# How to remove the App installed screen after app installation in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am installing the app programatically using intent. After installation i am getting a screen as App installed. How do i remove or not to have this screen coming up after installation is completed.

Following is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    ); // without this flag android returned a intent error!             
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Comment: You could build your own custom ROM that does not offer this activity, then install that ROM on your device.

Comment: Is there any example or tutorial for building the custom ROM and installing?

Comment: Is there any programmatic way other than having custom ROM?

Comment: Before down voting the question. Let me know why is this down voted.  I don't know who has done it.